# Limiting screen size of android app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What I would like is to limit the screen size of my android app.
e.g.

On a phone, fullscreen, the app appears on the whole screen.

On tablets, fullscreen, app appears in a rectangular in the middle of the screen, the rest is blacked out.

How would I go about doing this?

- I currently control the layout in code, so not in the xml files
- Using a LinearLayout

Thanks in advance,

EDIT : Reworded the question

Comment: "On tablets, non fullscreen" even if another app is running? I'm afraid you can only do this on certain devices -- some Samsung devices -- and even then, it might not be what you want...

Comment: Hi chris, actually what I meant is fullscreen, but the app only appears in a rectangular in the middle, the other parts maybe just blacked out. Let me reword the question.

Comment: Post your layout's code, let's see how you are populating the views.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence)? This should help

> On a phone, it is fullscreen.
>
> On tablets, non fullscreen, occupies a small rectangle in the middle
>   of the screen.

I think you mean your app UI will occupy the whole screen (Except Status Bar and Navigation Bar) and for Tablets, it will become a Dialog? If so, this is possible by specifying Activity Theme that ends with `[Theme].DialogWhenLarge` like the sample code below

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge" />
```